# Command to generate a file with a list of all files with name ".htaccess"

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface

How do I write a command that searches the `/var/www` directory for all files with the name ".htaccess" and outputs the full location/path to each of the .htaccess files into a file?

This would save me a lot of time if this is possible with a unix command. I am running debian, lenny if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find /var/www -name .htaccess > yourfilelist
```

will do this. For more details, see `man find`.